unusual segno before barline in baroque score?
In a baroque score (from sonata 1 for 2 flutes by Jean-Daniel Braun, op. 4), I spotted this mysterious segno symbol before a double barline in the middle of a movement.  What might it mean?

There is a similar symbol at the end of the movement, so maybe it is some kind of repeat?  The end also says Da capo at the same place, so maybe it means repeat this section once and then go back to the beginning (to the fine, which is also marked)?


If I had to hazard a guess, I'd guess that's a repeat sign.

It certainly looks like a segno repeat, but I don’t understand why they haven’t just used the regular repeat barlines ( ||:  :|| ) in this instance.

@ElementsInSpace Since the composer use normal repeat signs in other places one would think that this particular sign means something else than a normal repeat.

It's a bit odd and inconsistent, but I think it just means "da capo."  Why that is marked explicitly in the second case and not in the first is beyond me.
It can't just mean "repeat," since normal repeat signs are used elsewhere, including elsewhere in this movement.  Note how there is above the sign, in both cases, a custos for each part indicating the first pitch of the movement, F♯ for the first and D for the second.  So I think the road map for the piece is:

Play from the beginning to fine, then repeat as indicated;
Play the next section until the first sign;
Play from the beginning to fine, repeat;
Play the section between the first sign and the second sign;
Play from the beginning to fine, repeat.

Note also that the sections preceding the signs are structurally similar: they both move to a related key (the first to the dominant and the second to the relative minor), they both begin with imitation (whereas the main section begins in parallel), and they're both 20 measures long.
There's another movement also marked "aria" in a later sonata in the same collection that has this form as well, which, as Elements In Space points out, is rondo form.  There are actual vocal arias with this form, too (e.g. Bach's "Schlummert ein" from BWV 82 and from Anna Magdalena's music book), though the far more common standard da capo form has only one contrasting middle section instead of two.

This is Rondo form: ABACA, right?

@ElementsInSpace yes.
